# Using Tasks as a way to separate computation of results from committing results

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

An API pattern we are considering for separating the work of calculating some results from the  committing of those results is:

```
    interface IResults { }
    class Results : IResults { }

    Task<IResults> CalculateResultsAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return Task.Run<IResults>(() => new Results(), ct);
    }

    void CommitResults(IResults iresults)
    {
        Results results = (Results)iresults;
        // Commit the results
    }
```

This would allow a client to have a UI that kicked off the calculation of some results and know when the calculation was ready, and then at that time decide whether or not to commit the results.  This is mainly to help us deal with the case where during the calculation, the UI will allow the user to cancel the operation.  We want to ensure that:

- The cancel UI is only shown while the action is still cancellable (i.e once we're in CommitResults, there is no going back), so once the `CalculateResultsAsync` task completes, we take down the cancel UI and as long as the user hasn't cancelled, go ahead and call the commit method.
- We don't want to have a case (i.e. a race condition) where the user hits cancel and the results are committed anyways.
- The client will never make use of `IResults` other than to pass it back to `CommitResults`.

**Question:**
The general question is: is this a good approach?  Specifically:

1. It doesn't feel right having this split into two methods since the client is never inspecting `IResults`, they are just handing it back to the Commit method.
2. Is there a standard approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a *very* standard pattern (if not the ideal pattern), especially when your Results object is immutable. We do this regularly in TPL-using code inside the Visual Studio codebase. Much happiness always exists when your asynchronous/parallel logic is processing data, and the mutating crap lives apart from that.

If you're familiar with or have heard of the "Roslyn" project, this is a pattern we're actually encouraging people to use. The idea is refactorings can process asynchronously in the background and produce an object just like your result one that represents the result of the refactoring being applied. Then, on the UI thread anybody can take one of those result objects and apply it, which goes and updates all your files to contain the new text.

I do find the entire IResults/Results thing a bit strange -- it's not clear if you're using this to hide implementations from yourself or not. If the empty interface and the cast bugs you, you could consider adding to IResult a commit method, which the result object implements. Up to you.

Comment: we ended up going with having an IResult that has a Commit method (as you suggested): that way there isn't the need to have two methods that represent one action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly would you need this pattern. To me, it seems that if you check the `CancellationToken` just before starting the commit, you're going to get exactly the same result, with simpler interface.

Comment: Then how would the user interface know when to close up the UI showing the cancel button (because I don't want the user to be able to click the cancel button if they cannot cancel the operation).

Comment: One advantage to what Matt is doing is by not giving the commit method the cancellation token, they can't screw things up and think they have to support cancellation. There's a few places in Roslyn internally where we have methods that have a big "DO NOT CHECK THE CANCELLATION TOKEN AFTER THIS POINT" comments which is definitely inelegant. Also, if commit has UI thread affinity, breaking it up further is a nice pattern.